# Passing a variable as parameter to the middleware (Laravel) - bad practice?

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, middleware

In my project i want to check if a user is in a certain group, to access the groups page.

To show the page i am using this route:

```
Route::get('/gruppen/{groupID}', 'GroupsController@show');
```

Then in the GroupController I am using a custom middleware to do the authenfication:

```
$this->middleware('checkGroup:' . request()->groupID)->only('show');
```

In my middleware i will check in a pivot(group_user) table if the logged in User has got a matching entry with the groupID.

Now I was wondering if it is considered bad practice to pass a variable to the middleware like this.
Also might there be a more efficient way to check whether the User is in this group?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: there would be a user_type or other pivot table with this detail to check in you middleware,  why you are passing from route param ?

Comment: You will have access to the`$request` object in your middleware class so you can just get the `groupId` from in there...or use a policy (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#writing-policies).